# Commuting material time derivative and material space derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, differentiation, commutator, continuum-mechanics

Let's note $x$ the coordinates in the current configuration and $\nabla$ the associated gradient; similarly, let's note $X$ and $\nabla_0$ for the reference configuration. I will also note the material time derivative $D/Dt$ by a superposed dot (following a system moving at velocity $v$) and the spatial time derivative $\partial/\partial t$ noted as such.

I know that the **material time derivative** commutes with the **spatial gradient** as follows:

$$\nabla\dot{S} = \dot{\overline{\nabla{S}}} + \nabla v\cdot\nabla{S}$$

I was wondering what would be the analogous formula when the gradient is wrt the **reference configuration** $\nabla_0$ and not the current configuration (still with a material derivative). Here's my attempt:

$$\nabla_0\dot{S} = \frac{\partial}{\partial X}\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial t} + v\cdot\frac{\partial S}{\partial x}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial S}{\partial X} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial X}\cdot\frac{\partial S}{\partial x} + v\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial X}\frac{\partial S}{\partial x} = \dot{\overline{\nabla_0{S}}} + \nabla_0 v \cdot \nabla S$$

where we can write $\nabla S=\nabla_0 S \cdot F^{-1}$ (using the chain rule), in order to have only material gradients ($F=\frac{\partial x}{\partial X}$ is the deformation gradient).

Any feedback welcome!

Comment: One would say "... commutes with ...", if they actually did, i.e. if the commutator is zero, which here it is not. In the second formula you are using $\partial_X \partial_t = \partial_t \partial_X$, which given $\partial_x \partial_t = \partial_t \partial_x$ would imply a time-independent $F$, wouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Perhaps the wording "commuting" is inadequate here, I mean whatever action is done when writing $\partial_x\partial_t=\partial_t\partial_x$. How would you call that? Let's say commute for now. 
Can't partial derivatives be commuted (even when replacing $x$ by $X$ in the equation right above)? I'm not sure to understand your point about time independence.

Comment: My point is: $\partial_t \partial_X S = \partial_t \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial X} \partial_x S\right) = \partial_t \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial X}\right) \partial_x S +  \partial_X \partial_t S$

Comment: Is that also true if I adopt a Lagrangian point of view, where the reference coordinate $X$ is my primary variable and the current coordinate is a function of it $x(X,t)$? I am unsure what the rule is for commuting partial spatial and time derivatives. Would it be true that I can commute $\partial_x$ and $\partial_t$ in an Eulerian perspective (but not $\partial_X$ and $\partial_t$), and vice-versa in a Lagrangian perspective?